# Compute probability that a random subset has a certain property (when we know probability for an arbitrary subset)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

Suppose we have a ground set $[n]:=\{1, \dotsc, n\}$.

Now, we pick a random subset $S \subseteq [n]$ u.a.r. among all the subsets of $[n]$ having size equal to $s$.

In general, if we know that for an arbitrary set $X \subseteq [n]$ of size $|X|=s$ a property holds with probability $p$, then we know that the probability that for all sets of size $s$ this property holds can be computed as

$$\text{Pr}[\text{for all sets of size } s \text{ property holds}]\geq 1- {n \choose s} (1-p),$$

using an union bound.

But now, what is the probability that the random subset $S$ has the property? Is there a general approach? I guess that the problem actually is quite trivial, but I do not see it.

Is it still $p$, because

$$\text{Pr}[\text{property holds for } S]= \sum_{X}\text{Pr}[S=X]p = p?$$

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You are right: once the randomness in choosing the set is independent from that in sets having the desired property, the probability in question is $p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow this makes sense for me for this quite trivial set-up. However, I am dealing with random graphs, and there it somehow is confusing for me. So if we know that the probability that a fixed subset of vertices has a certain property (e.g. span a certain subgraph) is very small, say $p$, but not small enough to "kill" the union bound, i.e. $1-{n \choose s}(1-p)$ is large. What can we then say about a random set? That it has this property with probability $p$ still? I guess somehow it is the same, but I'm confused nevertheless.. Sorry for the stupid question..

Comment: Is there a difference between "arbitrary" and "chosen at random"?

Comment: Well, for me actually it is? But that might exactly be what I do not understand. For me "arbitrary" means: no matter which set you choose, it holds. For a "random" subset it could be that with low probability it does not hold, but with high probability it holds for a randomly chosen set... So it need not hold for all, but the probability that it holds for the chosen one is high. Since all the sets are chosen with the same probability, it then means that the property should hold for a large fraction of the sets. So "arbitrary"="for all" and "random"="for a large fraction".

Comment: Maybe, if someone wants to help me with it, I wonder about the question: 

Consider a deterministic graph on $n$ vertices having minimum degree $\geq \delta$.
For a fixed vertex $x$ and some fixed subset $X$ of vertices, we now can compute the number of neighbors of $x$ in $X$. When $X$ is fixed, then it could be that all the $d$ neighbors of $x$ are not in $X$. So it could be that $d(x,X)=0$. However, if we choose $S$ to be random, then this shouldn't happen, so $d(x,S) >0$ whp? (this problem also concerns random graphs in the end, but this is the easiest version I could think of)

Comment: Also, what might get some insight: When all the sets are the same (in terms of having a certain property), then "arbitrary"="random". But it might be that $p$ is not the exact probability but just a bound, and not each set is the same. So then there must be a difference between a random and an arbitrary subset, I guess.. So is this what you meant, @drhab ?

Comment: For arbitrary you say: "no matter which set you choose, it holds". But what exactly is **it** here? I would say: the fact that the probability that this set has the property is $p$.

Comment: Well I guess we wrote it at the same time. So what I actually mean, and what I formulated in a wrong way in the original post, is that the sets need not be the same, so not all have this property with probability $p$ but, say, with probability $\geq p$. I'm sorry for the confusion! This is because I am so confused about this "two kinds of randomness" questions...

Comment: Then, of course, the probability in question will be at least $p$ as well. But maybe you need to write the question more precise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and sorry for bothering you with my not-well-posed questions. But sometimes if one is confused, it is even difficult to write the correct questions down. So I tried to break the problem into two things and posted it here again: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779403/arbitrary-vs-random-subsets-computing-probabilities
Would be really nice of you if you could take a look at it.